# Magento 2 How to hide free shipping method at checkout?

Tags: magento2.3, event-observer, shipping-methods, plugin, free-shipping

We are using this plugin -

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:ObjectManager/etc/config.xsd">
    <type name="Magento\Quote\Model\ShippingMethodManagement">
        <plugin name="shipping_method_management" type="Xyz\AdvancedTax\Plugin\Model\ShippingMethodManagement" disabled="false"/>
    </type>
</config>



<?php
namespace Xyz\AdvancedTax\Plugin\Model;

class ShippingMethodManagement {

    public function afterEstimateByExtendedAddress($shippingMethodManagement, $output)
    {
        return $this->filterOutput($output);
    }
    private function filterOutput($output)
    {
        $free = [];
        foreach ($output as $shippingMethod) {
            if ($shippingMethod->getCarrierCode() != 'freeshipping' && $shippingMethod->getMethodCode() != 'freeshipping') {
                $free[] = $shippingMethod;
            }
        }
        //print_r($free->getData());
        if ($free) {
            return $free;
        }
        return $output;
    }
}
```

It is only hiding for guest customer but it is not hiding when customer login.

Answer (score 0):

You have to work on `\Magento\Quote\Model\ShippingMethodManagement::estimateByAddressId`.

Comment: you mean use this - afterEstimateByAddressId ?